# Service Worker Update angular

Tags: angular, angular-service-worker

I want to implement a version check/update on my angular app.

Read the doc and so on, and I really don't get the thing of asking the user to reload the application. I don't remember any application asking for that.

1. I could not find much info about this so far, so I was wondering if there are Best Practices on this topic.
2. What I'm currently doing is calling a function during ngOnInit in my app.component so if it has to reload it will do so at bootstrap, then I check for updates after a given amount of time.
3. It's said that calling activateUpdate() can break the app due to version mismatch, but is reloading the page enough ?

My service

```
export class SwService {
  private readonly _is_app_stable$!: Observable<boolean>;
  private readonly _interval$!: Observable<number>;
  private readonly _after_interval_since_app_stable$!: Observable<number | boolean>;
  constructor(
    private readonly _updates: SwUpdate,
    private readonly _app_ref: ApplicationRef,
    private readonly _env_service: EnvService,
  ) {
    this._is_app_stable$ = this._app_ref.isStable.pipe(first(is_stable => is_stable));
    this._interval$ = interval(this._env_service.refresh_app_inteval * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    this._after_interval_since_app_stable$ = concat(this._is_app_stable$, this._interval$);
  }

  refresh_application(): void {
    this._is_app_stable$.subscribe(d => console.log('APP STABLE ???', d));
    if (this._updates.isEnabled) {
      this._after_interval_since_app_stable$
        .pipe(
          take(1),
          switchMap(async () => {
            this._check_update_status();
          })
        )
        .subscribe();
    }
  }

  private _check_update_status(): void {
    this._updates.versionUpdates
      .pipe(
        take(1),
        switchMap(async evt => {
          switch (evt.type) {
            case 'VERSION_DETECTED':
              console.log(`Downloading new app version: ${evt.version.hash}`);
              break;
            case 'VERSION_READY':
              console.log(`Updating app from ${evt.currentVersion.hash} to ${evt.latestVersion.hash}`);
              await this._apply_update();
              break;
            case 'NO_NEW_VERSION_DETECTED':
              console.log(`App is up to date with version :  ${evt.version.hash}`);
              break;
            case 'VERSION_INSTALLATION_FAILED':
              console.log(`Failed to install app version '${evt.version.hash}': ${evt.error}`);
              break;
            default:
              console.log('Could not verify update status');
              break;
          }
        })
      )
      .subscribe();
  }

  private async _apply_update(): Promise<void> {
    await this._updates
      .activateUpdate()
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Successfully updated application');
        document.location.reload();
      })
      .catch(e => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log(`Error while updating client : ${e}`);
        document.location.reload();
      });
  }
}
```